# Screen on Lenovo W530 turns on and off every second upon startup

Tags: 16.04, display, flicker

I had installed Ubuntu Mate 17.04 and upon starting up my laptop after attempting to upgrade to 17.10, my screen just turns on and off every one second or so. I can't even get to the login screen. Booting from a live USB works just fine, however.

I should note that I encountered the same problem in the same laptop using Kubuntu 17.04, except that happened without any do-release-upgrade'ing.

I just installed all my applications and school documents, as well as getting Space Quest 4 working, so I want to avoid reinstallation, if possible.

The laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad W530
with 4GB RAM,
an Nvidia Quadro M1000M,
and an Intel Core i5 vPro processor.
The laptop originally came with Windows 7, if that has any bearing.

Comment: You need Nvidia drivers for the Quadro M1000M (version 384.90).

Comment: I already have the drivers for my Quadro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never you people mind, I got it working. I'll explain how for future reference.

So, to fully describe my problem, upon starting up, my computer would show the Ubuntu MATE splash screen, then go straight to a black screen with my cursor. The monitor on my laptop would turn off, then on, forever. It would never go to a login screen.

So, I went into a live boot of Ubuntu, mounted my hard drive (/dev/sda6) as /mnt as rw, chroot'd into it, logged in, then did:

sudo dpkg --configure -a

then suddenly I could get to the login screen! Upon logging in, it put me back to the login screen, so I deleted ~/.Xauthority, then my laptop was perfectly fixed!

I really should have mentioned that I had just done a botched do-release-upgrade. That was foolish of me. But at least I deducted how to fix my laptop, and now I feel like a god.

By the by, future updates worked fine, so I'm in the clear.